# Native resolution not occupying the entire screen

Tags: display, resolution

I just got a [new monitor](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/computer-peripherals/monitors/consumer/LS22A350HS/XK/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&subsubtype=series-3-led). The native resolution seems to be 1920x1080 (16:9). But when I set that, Ubuntu occupies only part of the screen, leaving a black border around. When I try setting another resolution like 1680 x 1050 (16:10), it fills the entire screen. But perhaps its a bit stretched out?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a monitor issue and not a software issue.

Check the monitor user manual http://www.manualowl.com/m/Samsung/S22A350H/Manual/193348 , and more specifically the section "3-1 Setting the Optimal resolution"

Comment: The monitor resoulution is already 1920x1080